# FullCalendar slotLabelInterval count

Tags: fullcalendar

I am working on a web page that has FullCalendar in it. I would like to make the agendaWeek-view show time from 06:00 to 22:00 with interval of 4 hours. The 06:00-22:00 time works as it should but how can I change the interval count to start from 06:00? It starts counting from 00:00 and now the first visible time label is 08:00 but I want it to be 06:00. In short, the calendar starts from 06:00 with no time labels on it until at 08:00.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure because you have not posted any code but I think this is what you are looking for. [slotDuration](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotDuration/) will let you change the interval where the calendar will display times. So if you set `slotDuration: '04:00:00'` it will only show a time interval every 4 hours. See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/duu0dx2t/416/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not what I'm looking for. slotDuration sets the length of the time slots as far as I know. If for example I set it to 4 hours and my calendar starts at 06:00 I wouldn't be able to place events at time like 08:00. The next possible place for event would be at 10:00, 14:00 and so on (although can't test that right now but that's how I think it works). Was my original question understandable? I have set minTime to 06:00, maxTime to 22:00 and slotLabelInterval is 04:00:00. I want the slotLabelInterval start counting from minTime rather than from 00:00 as it does.